# Retrieving data from a database with relationships

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve some data from my database, I have already made the right relationships inside the database but I just can't get my head around which query to use.

Here is a visual representation of the different relationships:
[image: phpmyadmin]

What I want is to get all data from clanwars aswel as all usernames from the users who have applied for these wars.

Can you guys help me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _Side note:_ Since your `password`-column is only 50 chars in length, it tells me that you're not using `password_hash()` to hash the passwords before you store them. You should do that...

Comment: Do some research on using `JOIN`s

Comment: @MagnusEriksson i am md5 encrypting the passwords, which works. or is this a bad idea?

Comment: @PatrickQ alright, thanks for leading me in the right direction

Comment: If you check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) for `md5()`, it says: _"Warning
It is not recommended to use this function to secure passwords, due to the fast nature of this hashing algorithm."_ so yes, it's a bad idea :-) Use PHP's [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) instead. They will give you a good and secure password hash. Just remember to change the size of the `password`-column since those hashes are longer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**All data from clan wars:**

```
select * from clanwars;
```

**All users that have applied to participate in a certain war:**

```
select playerid from applications where warid = <war_id>;
```

Make sure to replace war_id with the desired war id you want to pull playerid's from.

**All users that have applied to a war at all:**

```
select distinct playerid from applications;
```

**All usernames that have applied to a war (using a subquery):**

```
select username from members where id in (select distinct playerid from applications);
```

My go to SQL resource is [www.w3schools.com/sql/](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/). Check it out when you get a chance.

Comment: I don't think the OP just wants the id's. That's probably not that useful. I think the OP wants all the player info so joins are most likely the way to go.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson all clanwar info and only the usernames is what I'm looking for

Comment: @CheapGamer - This would only give you the playerid's, not the usernames. Join's the way to go.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I know, but when using the solution Morefoam provided I get multiple rows belonging to the same war each with a different user, this isn't bad but this would cause problems when displaying each war and its respective applicants. I think I'll just use two queries, one to get all wars and one to get all users who have applied for the wars.

Comment: I meant to write The Impaler instead of MoreFoam, excuse me

Comment: Edited my answer to include a query that will return the usernames of all players who have applied to a war. Uses a subquery. Joins will also work. The Impalers answer is a good example of a join.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
select w.*, m.username
  from clanwars w
  join applications a on a.warid = w.id
  join members m on m.id = a.playerid
```

Comment: This answers my question, but I now realize that this is not the best way to do it. Thanks anyways

Comment: :) Happens all the time. What do you actually need?

Comment: Well the solution MoreFoam provided is good, I just switched up your usernames in my previous comment and I can't edit it just yet haha

Comment: A word of advice. The solution by @MoreFoam will work well. However is suffers from the "N+1" problem. I requires a high numbers of SQL executions; for high number of rows that could become slow. Other than that, it's good.

Comment: Which approach would you suggest then? Filtering the output from the join query you provided?

Comment: Not at all. The solution from @MoreFoam is good for a low number of rows. Think, less than 10 thousand rows. If you have more, then you'll need to make an effort in optimization.

Comment: Since our Competitive part of the clan only exists out of 17 players atm this won't be a problem, thanks for the answers!